# how to use averageif function to judge logic value in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data like this:

```
0.00383
#N/A
#N/A
#N/A
0.385
#N/A
#N/A
#N/A
0.699
#N/A
#N/A
#N/A
1.091
#N/A
#N/A
1.42
#N/A
#N/A
#N/A
1.76
#N/A
```

I plan to use averageif function to calculate the average value like this:

```
=AVERAGEIF(G3:G23,NOT(NA()))
```

but I got only `#N/A`
can anyone tell me why I'm wrong?
I'm using office 2016 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
=AGGREGATE(1, 6,A:A )
```

- first paremeter `1` specifies `Average`
- Second parameter `6` specifies "ignore errors", which usually is the case of `#NA`

Also possible is

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A, "<9e99")
```

Any numeric comparison `<` systematically fails whenever the cell is not numeric.

But the first option is usually preferable, the second one being a *"workaround"* before the advent of the `Aggregate` function.

Comment: thanks a lot! It helps, but can you tell me what's wrong with my using of averageif?

Comment: @user6769374 because that's not correct syntax for the criteria. Take a look [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) for more information about criteria formats.

Comment: I've seen that already, does that mean I cannot use logic value in averageif function?

Comment: @user6769374 the "logic" in "*IF" functions is limited to very basic comparisons.

Comment: @user6769374 to use your original formula, it would be `=AVERAGEIF(G1:G23,"<>#N/A")`